# Update Query not working inside postgresql function but it works fine outside function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating function in postgresql to update table. when I ran single function it works fine but I use same query inside function it wont works.

> ```
> update house1 SET calendar=
>  'H'||' '||house_num::text||' '||left(to_char(sdate, 'Mon'),2) ||' to '  || to_char(sdate, 'DD') ||to_char(rdate, 'Mon-DD')
>  where id=1
> ```

Inside function I wrote following query

```
begin
execute
'UPDATE house1 SET calendar = '
||quote_nullable( 'H')||' '||house_num||' '||left(to_char(sdate, 'Mon'),2) ||' to '  || to_char(sdate, 'DD') ||to_char(rdate, 'Mon-DD')
|| ' WHERE' ||  'stage'
'>=' || quote_nullable(0) ;
END
```

It generates following error

> ERROR:  column "house_num" does not exist.

Please help me

Comment: I don't think you need a dynamic statement in your function : `EXECUTE (...)`. Just try to insert the first UPDATE statement in your function body and share the result.

Comment: you should be using `format()` to build dynamic SQL strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use the `execute` statement in function?

You can use update statement directly in function (When using the `execute` statement if you need to build dynamic query)

```sql
create or replace function function_name()
   returns void 
   language plpgsql
  as
$$
begin
 update house1 SET calendar=
 'H'||' '||house_num::text||' '||left(to_char(sdate, 'Mon'),2) ||' to '  || to_char(sdate, 'DD') ||to_char(rdate, 'Mon-DD')
 where stage >= 0;
end;
$$;

select function_name();
```

Comment: execute 
     'UPDATE ' || table_name_||' '  
     || 'SET   ' || quote_ident(calCol) || '=' || quote_nullable(calConcat)   || ' '   'H' 
  || house_num::text  || ' S' || stage::text || ' ' ||   
  left(to_char(sdate, 'Mon'),2) ||' to '  || to_char(sdate, 'DD') ||    
  to_char(rdate, 'Mon-DD')   
 || 'WHERE ' || quote_ident(calcol)  || '>=' || quote_nullable(refCol); 
  --'>='  || 0 ;

but I want to create this function with dynamic parameter